# Comma in conditional sentence and in antithesis

Tags: punctuation, commas, conditionals

I've got a couple questions:

- Should I always put comma between condition and consequence parts, like in the following sentence:

  > If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.
- Should I always put comma in the sentences similar to the following (I may be wrong, but I think it's called antithesis):

  > It rains, but children continue to play football.

Comment: If you speak out the first sentence, you'd pause in between "questions" and "don't", so a comma is definitely warranted. For the second, "It's raining, but..." sounds better to my ears at least, but your construction is not ungrammatical. Yes, the comma ought to be there, too.

Comment: J. M.: I can remember that someone on EFnet mentioned that for example `It's always raining in London.` (present progressive) may be used to emphasize one's irritation about a phenomenon which happens often.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I always put comma between condition and consequence parts, like in the following sentence?

```
If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.
```

You should.  In the example you provided, "If you have any questions" is a dependent clause, and as such, it must be followed by a comma since it precedes the independent clause.

> Should I always put comma in the sentences similar to the following (I may be wrong, but I think it's called antithesis)?

```
 It rains, but children continue to play football.
```

Yes, you should. In the example you gave, "children continue to play football" is an independent clause. Whenever "but" (or any other conjunction) is used to join two independent clauses, it should be preceded by a comma.

Comment: Are you sure both `It rains` and `but children continue to play football.` are independent clauses? [There are](http://www.englishlanguageguide.com/english/grammar/clause.asp) two connected depended and independed clauses appropriately delimited by a comma: `Jim studied in the Sweet Shop for his chemistry quiz, but it was hard to concentrate because of the noise.`

Comment: `It rains` is an independent clause. `children continue to play football` is an independent clause. `but children continue to play football` is a dependent clause because of the included `but`. In the same way, `it was hard to concentrate because of the noise` is independent. However, `but it was hard to concentrate because of the noise` is a dependent clause. Rightly, an independent clause and a dependent clause should be delimited by a comma, but this is equivalent to two independent clauses connected with a conjunction preceded by a comma.

Comment: I had an English teacher who promoted the idea that, for very short sentences, one may sometimes omit the comma between independent clauses. The main example given was "Live and learn", which flows better than "Live, and learn". I think the similar sentences "I work and I get by" and "I try but I fail" might also be acceptable. While trying to come up with examples, I noticed that sometimes the alternate meaning of "but" as used in "If you would but listen to me..." sometimes caused some difficulty in parsing the sentence without a comma, although "I try but I fail" seems to avoid this.

Comment: Mitch, your teacher was right. I try to avoid unnecessary comma use myself. Back in the day, I wasn't taught to use a comma before a conjunction. In current English, though, "I try but I fail" may be pushing it. I would use a comma. One will find, though, that in a lot of informal writing, many of these comma rules go unobserved. However, in the example "If you would but listen to me...", a comma is not needed because "but" functions here as an adverb, not a conjunction!

Comment: @Jimi Oke, Yes I know about "but" functioning as an adverb; what I meant is that, in a proposed example sentence like "I do but he doesn't", the reader may initially interpret the word "but" as an adverb and have to revise that interpretation after reading the rest of the sentence, whereas the sentence "I do, but he doesn't" does not cause this problem.

Comment: @Mitch: Sorry for the late response, but thanks for the clarification. (I actually paused before using a comma in the previous sentence!) I do you see your point now. Apologies for the rather unnecessary lecture!

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Don't worry about it.. I think the fact that I was near the character limit for my first comment may have reduced the clarity at the end. I also didn't notice until just now that I used the word "sometimes" redundantly, heh.

Answer (score 3):

(Due to insistence)

If you speak out the first sentence, you'd pause in between "questions" and "don't", so a comma is definitely warranted. (If you have any questions, [pause] please don't hesitate to ask.)

For the second sentence, "It's raining, but..." sounds better to my ears at least, but your construction is not ungrammatical. Yes, the comma ought to be there, too.