# Placing a comma after a conditional statement

Tags: punctuation, commas, conditionals

I've always had difficulties in figuring out where commas should be placed. For example, in a phrase containing a conditional statement, how should I write...

- If they don't arrive by noon, she'll be worried.
- If they don't arrive by noon she'll be worried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma in conditional sentence and in antithesis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/comma-in-conditional-sentence-and-in-antithesis).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So far as I understand it: if you are putting the conditional statement first, you should put the comma at the end of it. You don't need a comma if the conditional statement comes afterwards.

Treat the condition as the independent clause and the result as the dependent as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Separation_of_clauses) describes.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a dependent (or subordinate) clause. Commas are required when starting a sentence with dependent clauses. See OWL Online Writing Lab. When the dependent clause is placed at the end of the sentence, a comma is not required. For example:

> If I went to London, I would visit Big Ben.
>
> I would visit Big Ben if I went to London.